# Injecting translate pipe to NgRx Effect and it throws NullInjectorError

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-services, angular-injector

I'm Injecting translate pipe to NgRx Effect and it throws NullInjectorError even though the pipe is provided in the module that holds the effect.
the package that I'm using for the translation is @ngx-translate/core.

Note: I was able to use the translatePipe in component scope.

module.ts:

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        OptimizationTabMainComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        OptimizationTabRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        TranslateModule,
        StoreModule,
        StoreModule.forFeature(StoreFeatures.Optimization, optimizationReducers),
        EffectsModule.forFeature([OptimizationMainEffects]),

    ],
    providers: [
        TranslatePipe
    ]
})
class OptimizationTabModule { }

export {OptimizationTabModule};
```

effect.ts:

```js
@Injectable()
export class OptimizationMainEffects {
    constructor(        
        private translateService: TranslatePipe,
    ) {
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            defaultLanguage: 'en',
            loader:          {
                provide:    TranslateLoader,
                useClass: LazyTranslateLoader
            },
            isolate: true
        }),
]
...
```

shared.module.ts

```js
const importsExports = [
    CommonModule,
    FlexModule,
    TranslateModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    NotificationsModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTooltipModule
];

@NgModule({
    imports: importsExports,
    exports: importsExports
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

[image]

Comment: is the module that holds your effects lazy loaded ? If so, then perhaps you need to import ngx-translate via additional configuration  https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#lazy-loaded-modules

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the translate module.
Docs: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#sharedmodule

```
@NgModule({
    imprts: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: Hi @timdeschryver, Thank you for your response.
I tried that and still, it throws the error.

Comment: A reproduction would be helpful @OrShalmayev